# How can i alter a div in my shopify theme to populate text from my product description

Tags: html, css, shopify

can anyone offer assistance on how I can alter a product page with individual tabs at the bottom (full description, delivery, returns info) In this case (size chart) is what i'm implementing. I need to get text from my product description which houses the size chart at the bottom of the description's paragraph.

presume i will need to use some type of html tag on my product description editor to signal where to split the text like a "!-- split -->"  move. but i also need to add something into my custom tabs div? which is below

```
        {% if section.settings.product_customtabs_1 %}       
        <div id="collapse-tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
          {% include 'display_product_detail_description' %}
          {% if settings.enable_multilang %}
          <div class="lang1">{{ section.settings.product_customtabs_content_1 | split: '|' | first }}</div>
          <div class="lang2">{{ section.settings.product_customtabs_content_1 | split: '|' | last   }}</div>
          {% else %}
          {{ section.settings.product_customtabs_content_1 | split: '|' | first  }}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
```

am i going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the custom `HTML` tag like `<!-- split -->` between backend product description editor and then separate the content over product page easily using liquid code filters.

```
{% assign productDes = product.description | split:'<!-- split -->' %}
{% assign productDesPart1 = productDes[0] %}
{% assign productDesPart2 = productDes[1] %}
```

you can use the `first`]and `last` array filters [first](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/array-filters#first) to get the values, but it works when there is a single `<!-- split -->` is used.

```
{% assign productDesPart1 = product.description | split:'<!-- split -->' | first %}
{% assign productDesPart2 = product.description | split:'<!-- split -->' | last %}
```

you can use something like this, but careful with the `HTML` tag into the backend editor and liquid code are some otherwise is not works.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I understand the theory you mentioned but when i put it into the div it doesnt get any content from my product description .  do you think it is because my product description isn't necessarily defined in this custom theme?

Comment: no issues where you put it, but you need to always aware of the HMTL tag structure, are you using it with product description or custom HTML inputs into the backend? I think it works in both cases, just need to change the code according to it.